# Azure Function for python (V2) does not detect trigger and not starting when deployed

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have deployed an Azure function for Python (V2) using GitHub CI/CD.

**Here's how my function_app.py file looked like**
[image: function_app.py code]

**And my project structure:**

[image: project structure]

**My github workflow deployment yml file**

```
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - app name

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.10' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'my-app-here'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
```

**And it runs locally perfectly:**
[image: Running locally]

**But when I deploy it to Azure:**
[image: Azure deployment]

**The azure does not detect the trigger**
[image]

Can anybody please help with this?

Comment: [Please do no post code in image format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). request you to add the code in question in text formate.

Comment: May I know why `local.settings_1.json` file is  created?

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to your code or file name or may be `local.settings_1.json` file, which is result in not able to sync or function not able to show in functions.

For reference check this [Issue Article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1338).

> #### Make sure Everything is correct, file names, code structure and syntax.

This worked for me.

#### My Directory:

[image]

**`function_app.py`:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.service_bus_queue_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", queue_name="mysbqueue",
                               connection="sb_queue_conn") 
def servicebus(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Queue trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**`main_funcsetting.yml`:**

```yaml
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/azure/functions-action
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure Functions: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - funcsetting

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.11' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip     
        
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'funcsetting'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx }}
```

#### Deployment:

[image]

[image]

##### `OUTPUT`:

**Local :**

[image]

**Azure :**

[image]